# Counting specific lines in a log file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a log file containing more than 100000 lines similar to the following

```
2016-11-08 17:04:01|x.x.x.x|xxxxxxxxxxxxx|x.x.x.x|1002|xxxx|xxxxxx|1|2|https://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx{"status":500,"body":""}
2016-11-08 17:04:02|x.x.x.x|xxxxxxxxxxxxx|x.x.x.x|1003|xxxx|xxxxxx|1|2|https://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx{"status":400,"body":""}
```

Please help me to write a script that will return a count of lines only with `"status":500`.

Comment: google `grep` and write your script

Comment: `grep -c "\"status\":500" filename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `grep -c "\"status\":500 /path/to/logfile.dat`

Comment: why struggle when you can use single quotes? `grep -c '"status":500'`